# How to convert string from cp1250 to utf-8 in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++builder

I maintain an application written in Borland C++ 6. This app is using SQLite database.

I am now extending it, so it can be used by unprivileged users, and so I had to move the database file to the home user directory. Unfortunately some of users have Polish national characters in their names, such as ą,ć,ę and some more. The system codepage is cp1250, but SQLite requires me to pass an utf-8 encoded path.

**So, basicly I need to convert a cp1250 encoded path**:

```
String path = "c:\documents and settings\User Name like Zażółć gęślą Jaźń\Application Data\...\MyDb.sqlite"
```

**to utf-8,** and then pass it to sqlite with path.c_str();

Does C++ builder have any class to convert charsets, or should I just map the short set of polish national character codes to their utf-8 representations?

Comment: By now you could have written the mapping and be done with it :)

Comment: I have some other things to do, and I have planned this task on afternoon. I know I could have mapped it fast, but I wanted to learn something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the documentation for C++ Builder (the links on Borland's page seem to be broken), but from what I recall, you can directly convert from AnsiString to WideString.

Once you have a UTF-16 string, you can use [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) Windows function, passing CP_UTF8 as a parameter.

Comment: Assigning an AnsiString to a WideString uses the OS default Ansi codepage for the conversion.  If you want to use a specific codepage, especially if it is different than the OS language, then you have to call MultiByteToWideChar() directly.